# Looking for the general term of the power series for $\frac{1}{\cos{x}-\cos{b}}$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

To finish my work, I need to obtain the general term of the power series of the below function:

$$\frac{1}{\cos{x}-\cos{b}}$$

where $b$ is any real number. Transcendent functions are welcome, I know it will be impossible to have a formula for this without a transcendent function.
Btw, I want this formula to be valid always (infinite radius of convergence).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Taylor. It won't come out pretty.... Perhaps an asymptotic estimate is enough?

Comment: For what interval would you like the power series to approximate?

Comment: I would like it to be valid for any real number, but I guess that's impossible, right? If so, it defeats my purpose.

Comment: What led you to ask this question? Some context on what you were trying to solve before asking this question would help.

Comment: As a function of $\ x\ $, $\ \frac{1}{\cos x- \cos b}\ $ has singularities at $\ \pm b + 2n\pi\ $ for every integer $\ n\ $, so its Taylor series will have a radius of convergence of $\ b_0=b \mod\hskip{-0.2em}(\, 2\pi\,)\ $, and the radius of convergence of any power series coinciding with it over some interval can have a radius of convergence of at most $\ \max(\,b_0, \pi-b_0)\ $.